# optimisation with inequality constraints

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm struggling with this question:
$ \max \{ \ln(y) - (x-1)^2 \} $

s.t. $x + y \leq t$ and $y > 0$

I'm trying to use the Lagrange/Kuhn-Tucker method but don't know how to progress after getting first order conditions $1/y = \lambda$ and $-2(x-1) = \lambda$ since there are two possible values for $x/y$ when I solve these in terms of my first constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformulating your problem as a minimization problem yields

$$
\begin{align}
& \min_{\mathbf{x}} \: (x_1-1)^2-\ln x_2 \\
\text{s.t.} \quad  & c_1(\mathbf{x}) = t - x_1 - x_2 \ge 0 \\
& c_2(\mathbf{x}) = x_2 \ge 0.
\end{align}
$$

KKT conditions:

$$
\begin{align}
& \nabla_x \mathcal{L} = \mathbf{0} \\
& \lambda_i \ge 0 \quad i=1,2 \\
& \lambda_i c_i(\mathbf{x}) = 0 \quad i=1,2.
\end{align}
$$

Stationarity of the Lagrangian requires that

$$
\begin{align}
& \lambda_1 = 2(1-x_1) \\
& \lambda_2 = 2(1-x_1) - x_2^{-1},
\end{align}
$$

and from the complementarity condition we have that

$$
\begin{align}
& 0 = 2(1-x_1)(t-x_1-x_2) \\
& 0 = (2(1-x_1)-x_2^{-1})x_2,
\end{align}
$$

which holds for

$$
\begin{align}
& x_1 = t - x_2 \\
& x_2 = \frac{1}{2}
\left(
-(1-t)+
\left(
(1-t)^2 + 2
\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\right) > 0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align} 
$$

Since $\lambda_i$ needs to be nonnegative for the $1^{\text{st}}$-order necessary conditions for a local minimum to hold, we check

$$
\begin{align}
& \lambda_1 =
(1-t)+
\left(
(1-t)^2 + 2
\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
> 0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \\
& \lambda_2 = \lambda_1 - x_2^{-1} \ge 0 \: \longleftrightarrow \: \lambda_1 x_2 - 1 = 0.
\end{align}
$$

Hence, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
\mathbf{x}^* = 
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
(1+t)-
\left(
(1-t)^2 + 2
\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
-(1-t)+
\left(
(1-t)^2 + 2
\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

is a candidate for the solution to the optimization problem.

The $2^{\text{nd}}$-order sufficient condition for $\mathbf{x}^*$ to be a local minimum is that (given the $1^{\text{st}}$-order necessary conditions hold)

$$\mathbf{s}^T H \mathbf{s} > 0 \quad \forall \mathbf{s} \in G^*,$$

where $G^*$ is the set of feasible directions and $H$ is the cost function's Hessian

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2 & 0 \\
0 & x_2^{-2}
\end{array}
\right).
$$

From this it follows that

$$\mathbf{s}^T H \mathbf{s} = 2s_1^2 + s_2^2x_2^{-2} > 0 \quad \forall \mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

The following plot shows the isoclines of the cost function, $c_1(\mathbf{x})=0$ for $t=5$ and the minimum $x^*=\left[3(1-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}), 2+3\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \right]^T$.

[image: Contour plot and $c_1(\mathbf{x})=0$]